# Can I select whether I want to use a function by itself or with its decorator function?

Tags: python, function, decorator, python-decorators

Consider this code:

```
def hello_decorator(func):
    def inner1(*args, **kwargs):
        
        print("before Execution")
        
        # getting the returned value
        returned_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after Execution")
        
        # returning the value to the original frame
        return returned_value
        
    return inner1


    # adding decorator to the function
    @hello_decorator
    def sum_two_numbers(a, b):
        print("Inside the function")
        return a + b
    
    a, b = 1, 2
    
    # getting the value through return of the function
    print("Sum =", sum_two_numbers(a, b))
```

Is there a way to use `sum_two_numbers(a,b)` without also having to invoke its decorator? Is there some keyword, or other way to do this?

Comment: No, this isn't possible if the decorator isn't specifically written to provide access to the underlying function.

Comment: Then is it correct to assume that the only reason to use a decorator function is to introduce the exact same functionality to lots of different functions? Because if I just wanted to introduce additional functionality to a function, I could just introduce it within its own body. Am I right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, and conversely, your functions can easily make use of existing decorators.

Comment: You don't have to use decorator syntax at all. You can always leave `sum_two_numbers` undecorated, and call `hello_decorator` on demand: `x = hello_decorator(sum_two_numbers)(3, 5)`.

Comment: You are right. A decorator for a single function only doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your function without the decorator and define a different function with the decorator.

```
def sum_two_numbers(a, b):
    print("Inside the function")
    return a + b

sum_with_decorator = hellodecorator(sum_two_numbers)
```

When you define a function using the decorator

```
@decorator
def some_function:
   ...
```

you are actually defining `some_function` as the result of the decorator applied to the original definition of the function. This is explained in [the python documentation of functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an argument to the wrapped function :

```py
def hello_decorator(func):
    def inner1(*args, simple_run=False, **kwargs):
        if simple_run:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("before Execution")

            # getting the returned value
            returned_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("after Execution")

            # returning the value to the original frame
            return returned_value

    return inner1


# adding decorator to the function
@hello_decorator
def sum_two_numbers(a, b):
    print("Inside the function")
    return a + b


a, b = 1, 2

# getting the value through return of the function
print("Sum =", sum_two_numbers(a, b, simple_run=True))
```

And if you have imported the decorator, you can do this way :

```py
from whatever import hello_decorator


def my_hello_decorator(func):
    def inner(*args, simple_run=False, **kwargs):
        if simple_run:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return hello_decorator(func)(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner


# adding decorator to the function
@my_hello_decorator
def sum_two_numbers2(a, b):
    print("Inside the function")
    return a + b


print("Sum =", sum_two_numbers2(a, b, simple_run=True))
```

Or as said keylongx3x0 you can create 2 different functions with and without decoration